# Totally isotropic subspace for bilinear pairing over ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, bilinear-form

Consider the following well-known inequality: Let $b$ be a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear pairing over a (finite-dimensional) $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ and $W$ a totally isotropic subspace. Then $\operatorname{dim}W \leq \frac{\operatorname{dim}V}{2}$.

I am trying to generalise a result for vector spaces to the case of modules over rings, and the proof of the former uses the above inequality to bound the dimension of a certain subspace, so I was wondering whether the analogous result exists for bilinear forms over rings (e.g. something bounding the length of a totally isotropic submodule in terms of the length of the ambient module). I don't have much experience with bilinear forms over rings, but the bibliography I found online does not mention a similar result.

It is possible that the notion of totally isotropic is substantially different over a ring due to the existence of zero-divisors, however I would be glad if someone could point out a related result (maybe dependent on some properties of the ring) or explain why such an inequality fails to hold over a ring.

Edit: I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5675) and wondering whether some of its results can be generalised to rings. My question refers to Lemma 7 (page 7, towards the end), more specifically the sentence starting with "Applying $(2)$ to $A=J_r$...". He proceeds to use the result I mentioned about vector spaces to obtain an inequality, and i was just wondering if the analogous reasoning can be used in a ring setting.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? It's possible there is a proof that doesn't require comparing dimensions explicitly, or that the result you are trying to prove suggests a particular generalization. It seems you are falling prey to the [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff can I send you a private message to explain the details?

Comment: If you're just trying to generalize a well-known result for vector spaces to modules, why the need for secrecy?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff It's not about secrecy: This is used to derive an inequality in the setting of a paper I am reading, but asking the question exactly would potentially require someone to read the paper and spend more of his time. Initially, I thought there would be a well-known result or counterexample to my question, but this may not be the case after all. Anyway, I have edited the question to include the paper.

Comment: Here is a rewording of your inequality that works for modules (but I don't know if it is true in that context): for every *maximal* totally isotropic subspace $W$ there is unique maximal totally isotropic subspace $W' \cong W$ such that $V = W \oplus W'$. Here "maximal" means that if $U \supseteq W$ is totally isotropic then $U = W$.